# How to convert react app to just ReactJS without needing to run npm start

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to convert an react app (NOT react native) just to react (so that I don't need to do npm start to run the app to begin setting the website?) Can anyone point me to resources relating to that please?

Comment: There is no "convert". The run is a convenience that includes a web server. Look at https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/ for how to "deploy" your code for hosting in a different environment.

Comment: Yes - instead of including the web server I just want to use react just like plain javascript (instead of using run to also provide the backend, because I use Django for that part). But I didn't see any html files that gives me the webpage I see at let's say localhost:3000 after I use the "run" command in the folder. I am just wondering is there a way change the react app back to plain javascript

Comment: The whole point of using ReactJS is to be more than "plain" JavaScript. Like I said, `run` is a convenience to compile and start a web server. You `build` to get a `build` folder that contains the compiled and minified libraries and packages required for it to run along with an index.html file. This is not code that you would work on directly due to the complexity of the React code itself, but what you would deploy to your internet hosted web-server.

Comment: I mean I am trying to convert the react app into just react, which I can then put in the script tag of an html file

Comment: Are you talking about something other than a React App created by create-react-app? Either way, your question does not make much sense to me as to what you have and what you think you can convert it to.

Comment: So I have a react app. Now I don't want to use npm start to run it. I want the react part to be embedded in a javascript file, which DOES NOT REQUIRE npm start for it to be effective.

Comment: Then build it and deploy it to a web server. The start command is a convenience for the developer. The build script is for deployment. Everything you need to know is at [https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/).